# Use another domain for a part of URL in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, dns, cross-domain, codeigniter-url

I want to make a website by `CI` that some people have a personal page like this

```
main-domain.com/index.php/sites/site_id/other-controller...
```

and I want to allocate a domain for everyone who has this site_id and visitors work by domains like this:

```
sub-site-domain.com/other-controller...
```

(just replace `main-domain.com/index.php/sites/site_id/ to sub-site-domain.com/` )
and I want to add domains too server but every domains use the core files and database for loading data . 
but use their own domain for internal links . 
how can I do that?
how can I add domains to server and whats the configuration? 
Can I user `session` of main-domain in sub-site-domains ?
whats a best solution to have a website like this?

Comment: "how can I do that?" you have to look for detect the subdomain over you app (use Hooks or Base Controller) and change base_url config to add this subdomain to your URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set dynamic base_url in config
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';`
or something like this

Comment: I found it out , I should save all domains in db , park all domains and leave base url blank , then check in controller what the base url is and load the page specially for that base url .

Comment: but can I use the session cross domains?
i mean save CI session in main domain and use it when visitors are in other domains ?

Comment: you can set $config['cookie_domain'] = ""; and sessions weel be "cross domain"

Comment: blank base_url is baaad idea... catch it from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']